# mongodb $addfields conditions is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lookup, mongoose-schema

i have used lookup for join 2 tables and i need to create 2 custom column so i have used the $addfields.
In $addfields, Member is not working but pqr is working.

```
I have a array of objects as a given below :


   await mongoose.models.abc.aggregate([
                    {
                        $lookup:
                        {`enter code here`
                            from: 'xyz',
                            localField: 'id',
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'my'
                        }   
                    },
                    {
                        $match: {
                            "my": { $ne: [] }
                        }
                    },
    
                    {
                        $addFields: {
                            pqr: { $cond: [{ $gte: ["$my.request", 1] }, { $sum: "$my.request" }, 0] },      
                            Member: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$myClub.request", 0] }, { $sum: "$myClub.request" }, 0] }, 
                        }
                    },
                ]);
    

[
        {
            "_id": "5ef05f650e26a40cb44a68d6",
            "createdAt": "2020-06-22T07:36:05.640Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-22T07:36:05.640Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "my": [
                {
                    "_id": "5eecc3c961767f21c8d694e0",
                    "request": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-19T13:55:21.573Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-19T13:55:21.573Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ef1b8f2c3d54e21f4d6b332",
                    "request": 0,
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-23T08:10:26.036Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-23T08:10:26.036Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

i need a output like this:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5ef05f650e26a40cb44a68d6",
            "createdAt": "2020-06-22T07:36:05.640Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-22T07:36:05.640Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "my": [
                {
                    "_id": "5eecc3c961767f21c8d694e0",
                    "request": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-19T13:55:21.573Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-19T13:55:21.573Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ef1b8f2c3d54e21f4d6b332",
                    "request": 0,
                    "createdAt": "2020-06-23T08:10:26.036Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-06-23T08:10:26.036Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "pqr":1, // for greater than eqaul to request=1
            "Member":1 // // for eqaul to request=0
        }
    ]
```